# Jenkins Error: [ANALYSIS-COLLECTOR] Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE

Tags: jenkins, pom.xml, pmd

Maven project in Jenkins results in FAILURE even though I am not publishing any pmd, checkstyle results. All of them are "not checked" in job configuration.
Compilation is actually success, but because of this error I am unable to trigger following job.

Error is:

```
[ANALYSIS-COLLECTOR] Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```